# Rails server returning HTML as opposed to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following link_to helper:

```
# app/views/users/show.html.erb 

<div id="social">
  <%= link_to "Friends", index_friends_path, id: "index_friends", remote: true %>
</div>
```

Since the value of `:remote` is set to `true`, my expectation was that the server would naturally try to return JavaScript with the AJAX response.

However, each time the link is clicked the AJAX response contains HTML from a file called `users/friends.html.erb` rather than JavaScript that dynamically renders the HTML from `users/_friends.html.erb` which would be the required behaviour.

My code for handling the request is as follows:

--Route:

```
# config/routes.rb

get '/index_friends' => 'users#friends'
```

--Action:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

def friends
  ...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

--js.erb template:

```
# app/views/friends.js.erb

$("#social").html("<%= j(render("friends")) %>");
```

The corresponding Rails log entry looks like this:

```
# log/development.log

Started GET "/index_friends" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-13 12:20:41 +0100
Processing by UsersController#friends as JS
```

Comment: You should use single quotes for your `render` parameter:
`$("#social").html("<%= j(render('friends')) %>");`

The log entry looks fine to me, as it is outputting "`UsersController#friends as JS`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `friends.js.erb` file was in the wrong directory (app/views/ as opposed to app/views/users).

To remedy this I ran the following in the terminal:

```
mv app/views/friends.js.erb app/views/users/friends.js.erb
```

Rails can now find this template since, by convention, the format instructions from the **users** controller point to files in app/views/**users**.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"data-type" => "js"
```

after

```
remote: true
```

Comment: This changed the log output to 

`Started GET "/index_friends" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-13 14:11:35 +0100`

`Processing by UsersController#friends as */*` 

But the response was the same